# Rethrow original exception when catch clause has another try-catch which throws nothing - equivalent in Reactive pipeline

Tags: java, reactive-programming, rethrow

I have a method which would be like this in traditional, imperative `try-catch` coding style:

```
void confirmCart(Checkout Order) {
    try {
        cartService.confirm(order.getCartId(), order.getCartHash());
    } catch (Exception ex1) {
        log.error("Confirm error: ", ex1);
        try {
            paymentService.cancel(order.getPaymentTransaction().getGatewayReference());
            throw ServiceException.wrap(ex1, CheckoutErrorCode.FAILED_CONFIRMING_CART);
        } catch (Exception ex2) {
            throw ServiceException.wrap(ex2, CheckoutErrorCode.FAILED_CANCELLING_PAYMENT);
        }
    }
}
```

The requirement is:

- when `cartService.confirm()` works, returns nothing
- when it fails, enter catch part, and try `paymentService.cancel()`
- if 2 fails, throw `ex2`
- if 2 succeeds, throw `ex1`(because `confirm()` has failed, anyway)
- depending on the exception thrown here, controller will do different things

Now, in Reactive style, it is like:

```
    Mono<Void> confirmCart(CheckoutOrder order) {
        return cartService.confirm(order.getCartId(), order.getCartHash())
                .onErrorMap(throwable -> {
                    log.error("Failed confirming cart! cartId: '{}', cartHash: '{}'", order.getCartId(), order.getCartHash(), throwable);
                    return ServiceException.wrap(throwable, CheckoutErrorCode.FAILED_CONFIRMING_CART);
                })
                .onErrorResume(throwable -> {
                    log.trace("Cancelling payment with order id {}", order.getId().toString());
                    // when confirmation fails, 1. cancel payment and 2. throw original exception to notify controller -> exception handler
                    return paymentService.cancel(order.getPaymentTransaction().getGatewayReference())
                            .map(paymentCancellationResponse -> {
                                log.trace("payment cancellation response: {}, order id: {}", paymentCancellationResponse, order.getId().toString());
                                return paymentCancellationResponse;
                            }).then()
                            .onErrorMap(e -> {
                                log.error("payment payment cancellation failed. ", e);
                                return ServiceException.wrap(e, CheckoutErrorCode.FAILED_CANCELLING_PAYMENT);
                            });
                });
    }
```

But, I have spent a lot of time playing with Reactive operators and cannot find any way to rethrow the original exception. The code above compiles, but will not throw the first exception when `confirmCart()` fails. **I guess because `onErrorMap()` and `onErrorResume()` cannot coexist; the latter one will be honored, maybe?**

I have tried with `onErrorMap` because besides, it should be synchronous: `confirmCart()` should wait for `paymentService.cancel()` if it fails.

I was playing with `then()`, `thenReturn()` and so on, but I can make it compile, but it does not return/rethrow the first confirmation exception.

```
return cartService.confirm(order.getCartId(), order.getCartHash())
        .onErrorResume(throwable -> {
            log.error("Failed confirming cart! cartId: '{}', cartHash: '{}'", order.getCartId(), order.getCartHash(), throwable);
            log.trace("Cancelling payment with order id {}", order.getId().toString());
            // when confirmation fails, 1. cancel payment and 2. redirect user to checkout page
            return paymentService.cancel(order.getPaymentTransaction().getGatewayReference())
                    .map(paymentCancellationResponse -> {
                        log.trace("payment cancellation response: {}, order id: {}", paymentCancellationResponse, order.getId().toString());
                        return paymentCancellationResponse;
                    }).thenReturn(
                        ServiceException.wrap(throwable, CheckoutErrorCode.FAILED_CONFIRMING_CART)
                    )
                    .onErrorMap(e -> {
                        log.error("payment payment cancellation failed. ", e);
                        return ServiceException.wrap(e, CheckoutErrorCode.FAILED_CANCELLING_PAYMENT);
                    }).then();
        });
```

In the test I have no exception thrown when `cartService.confirm()` fails.